# Definition of functions in the induced space from parabolic induction

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, reductive-groups

Let $P$ be a parabolic subgroup of a connected, reductive group $G$ over a $p$-adic field.  Let $M$ be a Levi subgroup of $P$, and let $N$ be the unipotent radical of $P$.  If $(\pi,V)$ is a smooth, irreducible representation of $M$, extend $\pi$ to a representation of $P$ by making it trivial on $N$, and let $\sigma = \operatorname{Ind}_P^G \pi$, the smooth representation of $G$ obtained by parabolic induction.

By definition, a function $f: G \rightarrow V$ lies in the space of $\sigma$ if the following conditions are met:

- $f$ is locally constant.
- $f(mng) = \pi(m)f(g)$ for all $m \in M, n \in N, g \in G$.
- There exists an open compact subgroup $K$ of $G$, depending on $f$, such that $f(gk) = f(g)$ for all $g \in G$ and $k \in K$.

Is the third condition redundant in this definition?  I know in the general case for smooth induction in totally disconnected groups, it is necessary, but I have thought that since $P \backslash G$ is compact, there should be some way to show the third condition from the first two.  I haven't been able to do this.  I have seen some authors leave out the third condition in the definition of parabolic induction.

Comment: In future please close your questions here or otherwise indicate that you've received an answer already on MO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third condition is indeed redundant whenever $\mathrm{supp}(f)$ is compact in $H\backslash G$. where $H$ is the subgroup being induced from.

Let $H$ be open such that $\mathrm{supp}(f)$ is compact in $G\backslash H$ (note that $f$ is not a function on $G/H$ but we can talk about its support as a global section of some nontrivial vector bundle on $H\backslash G$, which after all is what induction is. Then we claim that $f$ is a smooth vector in $\sigma$. For every $x\in G/H$ there is an open compact subgroup $K_x$ of $G$ such that $f$ is constant on $xK_x$ by smoothness of $f$ just as a function. As the support of $f$ is compact modulo $H$ there are finitely-many $x_i$ such that the support is contained in $H(\bigcup_ix_iK_{x_i})$. Now clearly $f$ is right-invariant under $\bigcap_iK_{x_i}$.

This argument is from p.58 of Ngo's notes on representations of p-adic groups. And of course, everything in this argument goes through for any td-group.

Comment: Dear @BartMichels the claim is not that $f$ is right-invariant with respect to $HxK_x$. It that is that $f$ is right-invariant with respect to $K:=\bigcap_iK_{x_i}$. The finiteness of this intersection is deduced from the compactness of the support of $f$ modulo $H$.

Comment: If you prefer, noting that $f(x_i)=f(x_iK_{x_i})$,  we have $f(hx_ik_i)=\pi(h)f(xk_i)=\pi(h)f(x_i)=f(hx_i)$ for any $k_i\in K_i$.

Comment: Right, thanks!${}$